# How to connect to specific cassandra node only

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have two docker cassandra container nodes acting as node1 and node2 in the same data center.

My aim is to have my java application will always connect to node1 and my adhoc manual queries should return from node2 only (There should not be any inter node communication for data)

Normally i can execute read/write queries on top of container1 or container2 using cqlsh. If i fire some queries on top of container1 using cqlsh will it always return the data from same container (node1) or it may route to another node also internally?

and I know coordinator node will talk with peer node for data request , what will happen incase of RF=2 and 2 nodes cluster will coordinator node itself be able to serve the data?

Here, RF=2, node=2, Consistency=ONE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have set up clusters before to separate OLTP from OLAP.  The way to do it, is to separate your nodes into different logical data centers.

So node1 should have it's local data center in cassandra-rackdc.properties to be in "dc1."

```
dc=dc1
rack=r1
```

Likewise, node2 should be put into it's own data center, "dc2."

```
dc=dc2
rack=ra
```

Then your keyspace definition will look something like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE stackoverflow
  WITH REPLICATION={'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','dc1':'1','dc2':'1'};
```

> My aim is to have my java application will always connect to node1

In your Java code, you should specify "dc1" as your default data center, as I do in this example:

```
String dataCenter = "dc1";

Builder builder = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(nodes)
                .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE))
                .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(
                                            new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.Builder()
                                            .withLocalDc(dataCenter).build()))
                .withPoolingOptions(options);
```

That will make your Java app "sticky" to all nodes in data center "dc1," or just node1 in this case.  Likewise, when you cqlsh into node2, your ad-hoc queries should be "sticky" to all nodes in "dc2."

*Note: In this configuration, you do not have high-availability.  If node1 goes down, your app will not jump over to node2.*

Comment: also can create whitelist policy to connect only to the 1 node and have a Cluster object for each. Alternatively can build own LoadBalancingPolicy that wraps others and checks if the Statement is an instance of one you create (extend StatementWrapper with field include a host name). Then you can pass the host along with the query and it will only hit that one directly.

Comment: It's not a good idea to stand up a loadbalancer in front of Cassandra.

Comment: Perfect Explanation !! Does it require to update seed ip of both DC's in cassandra.yaml files ?

Comment: @Sathish It doesn't require it, no.  You should be able to use whatever seed node strategy that you were using before.